# pandas efficient dataframe set row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First I have the following empty DataFrame preallocated:

```
df=DataFrame(columns=range(10000),index=range(1000))
```

Then I want to update the `df` row by row (efficiently) with a length-10000 numpy array as data. My problem is: I don't even have an idea what method of DataFrame I should use to accomplish this task.

Thank you!

Comment: this will be quite inefficient. Better to construct the frame column by column then transpose at the end.

Comment: If you already have the numpy array as data, why not put it into the DataFrame constructor??

Comment: @AndyHayden,actually I have a list of generators as the return value of some function, and every generator in the list will be a numpy array (serves a row in the frame) once I `list()` it. Do you think it more efficient to `list()` them all at the same time?

Comment: If you can do it with list (memory wise) it'll be efficient. Another option, if memory was an issue, is to do it chunkbychunk (i.e. read it in several pieces and concat the result).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's 3 methods, only 100 columns, 1000 rows

```
In [5]: row = np.random.randn(100)
```

Row wise assignment

```
In [6]: def method1():
   ...:     df = DataFrame(columns=range(100),index=range(1000))
   ...:     for i in xrange(len(df)):
   ...:         df.iloc[i] = row
   ...:     return df
   ...:
```

Build up the arrays in a list, create the frame all at once

```
In [9]: def method2():
   ...:     return DataFrame([ row for i in range(1000) ])
   ...:
```

Columnwise assignment (with transposes at both ends)

```
In [13]: def method3():
   ....:     df = DataFrame(columns=range(100),index=range(1000)).T
   ....:     for i in xrange(1000):
   ....:         df[i] = row
   ....:     return df.T
   ....:
```

These all have the same output frame

```
In [22]: (method2() == method1()).all().all()
Out[22]: True

In [23]: (method2() == method3()).all().all()
Out[23]: True


In [8]: %timeit method1()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.76 s per loop

In [10]: %timeit method2()
1000 loops, best of 3: 7.79 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit method3()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.33 s per loop
```

It is CLEAR that building up a list, THEN creating the frame all at once is orders of magnitude faster than doing any form of assignment. Assignment involves copying. Building up all at once only copies once.

Comment: I've just tried
`def method4():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(100),index=range(1000))
    for i in xrange(len(df)):
        df.values[i,:]=row
    return df`

and it's about 40% faster than method2(). I understand .values assignment is not always type safe, but in case you know your df structure, it should be okay. Is that right?

Comment: Or, replacing the loop and just assigning directly, `df.values[:,:] = row`, which works as the row is repeated row-wise upon assignment, gives you further 2X speedup, overall 4 times faster than `method2()`. I'm getting 25.5 ms, 15.8 ms, and 5.83 ms per loop for method two, four, and five, respectively.

Comment: Not important for the question but I find df1.equals(df2) to be much more readable than (df1 == df2).all().all(), just throwing it out there for anyone not aware of the equals method for comparing dataframes

Comment: .equals() is newer that this post - maybe was 0.14 or 0.15

Answer (score 1):

```
df=DataFrame(columns=range(10),index=range(10))
a = np.array( [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9] )
```

Update row:

```
df.loc[2] = a
```

Using Jeff's idea...

```
df2 = DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(10,10), index=arange(10))
df2.head().T
```

I have written up a notebook answering the question: 
https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/hrojas/pandas%20efficient%20dataframe%20set%20row