# How to set row value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to set the first row's value of a column for every group to False.

`start_ix = group.head(1).index`

`print(start_ix)`

> Int64Index([20], dtype='int64')

`print df.iloc[start_ix]['start']`

> 20    False
>
> Name: start, dtype: bool

`df.iloc[start_ix]['start'] = True`

But the value stays `False` upon inspecting the DataFrame.

Comment: try `df.ix[start_ix,'start'] = True`

Comment: @EdChum thanks, that worked; would you might posting an answer with an explanation? I don't get it, yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas efficient dataframe set row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18771963/1278112)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically what you tried is what is called chained indexing and may or may not work:

```
df.iloc[start_ix]['start'] = True
```

It may help to think of this as chaining function calls, the problem here is that sometimes it returns a view which is what you intended, but other times it returns a copy resulting in no change in the original df.

So you should use `ix` which allows you to be explicit in indexing by integer value (or label) and then specifying the column label you want to set the data:

```
df.ix[start_ix,'start'] = True
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) detail the recommended methods, normally a warning will be raised when you are setting the value of a potential copy but it cannot catch all instances.

**Update**

Since version [`0.20.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated) `ix` is deprecated in favour of `loc` so the above becomes

```
df.loc[start_ix,'start'] = True
```

Comment: I thought that error occurred when I tried changing the value on the group and not the dataframe. I see now it applies at how I'm accessing the dataframe as well, thanks

Comment: `Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.` [ix-indexer-is-deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated)

Comment: @ShiheZhang sure will update, note that I answered this 3 years ago, plus I've answered quite a few `pandas` questions so there will be a lot of of answers that can be done differently or are unsupported in recent versions

Comment: Don't take it personally, just mention this in case others search this answer later.

Comment: @ShiheZhang I don't have an issue, I always update my answers when prompted especially when there are better ways to do things, just pointing out that `pandas` in particular changes rapidly