# Loop through parameter dictionary and create dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a faster/better way to set parameters and then use them to set values in a dataframe? See basic code example below.

```
  df_loop = pd.DataFrame(columns=['streak', 'bet', 'runs'], index=np.arange(1,100,1))

params = {
        'streak_game' : [3,4,5,6,7],
        'initial_bet' : [50, 100, 150, 200, 250],
        'run_diff_abs' : [x for x in range(150, 40,-10)]
         }

for i in params['streak_game']:
    streak_game = i
    for j in params['initial_bet']:
        initial_bet = j
        for k in params['run_diff_abs']:
            run_diff = k

           # actual code is more complex, but I am setting a bunch of values similar to below
            for idx, row in df_loop.iterrows():
                df_loop.loc[idx, 'streak'] = i
                df_loop.loc[idx, 'bet'] = j
                df_loop.loc[idx, 'runs'] = k
```

Actual dataframe is about 4,600 rows. But I plan on creating larger data sets to test my logic.

Comment: This previous SO post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771963/pandas-efficient-dataframe-set-row

Comment: @chasedcribbet Just curious if you need the df_loop with just 99 rows? Or you actually want to just make a dataframe with the parameters?

Comment: the parameters are used in more complex logic steps to create values, which I am putting into new columns. In theory, I could probably create lists only instead of putting into a dataframe, perform the mathematical operations on the lists, and then store the results in a dictionary. Then maybe look at the top n iterations and create dataframes for those only to analyze the results. Sorry--probably too much info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
import itertools
out = df_loop.join(pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*params.values()),columns= params.keys()))
```

Comment: Woah... fancy smancy!  splat unpacking, itertools, dictionary keys and pandas dataframe joins.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the reason you initialize the dataframe with `np.nan`. However, in your code, you should first initialize the parameters in a new variable before assigning it to the dataframe.

```
my_param = [(i,j,k) for i in params['streak_game'] for j in params['initial_bet'] for k in params['run_diff_abs']]
```

Next, instead of using `iterrows`, you can just use `iloc` to do so.

```
for i in range(len(df_loop)):
    df_loop.iloc[i] = my_param[i]
```

Too many nested loops will just cause redundance in your code.

Comment: I just usually always initialize with np.Nan when I am grinding thru/building stuff. Probably not a great habit

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df_loop = pd.DataFrame(columns=['streak', 'bet', 'runs'])

params = {
        'streak_game' : [3,4,5,6,7],
        'initial_bet' : [50, 100, 150, 200, 250],
        'run_diff_abs' : [x for x in range(150, 40,-10)]
         }
list = []
count = 0
for i in params['streak_game']:
    streak_game = i
    for j in params['initial_bet']:
        initial_bet = j
        for k in params['run_diff_abs']:
            run_diff = k
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[i,j,k]],columns=['streak', 'bet', 'runs'])
            df_loop = pd.concat([df_loop,df2])
```

Comment: The OP has initial dataframe with 99 rows, but you have 374 rows in the result.